# How to make text that never be converted to date after exporting to excel?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I have a text like:     04-4476

But after exporting it to excel it converted to date like:    Apr-76

Expected result is the original text i.e.  04-4476

CODE for export is like:  ws.Write(string.Format("04-4476"));

I'm not able to access excel so I can't change the formatting

Comment: How do you export the text? Can you pls show us your codesection?

Comment: That has nothing to do with programming, but with excels strategy to try to guess the actual data-type that fits your input. Just change the format by right-clicking the appropriat column in excel and set the type to "text".

Comment: See my edit @HimBromBeere

Comment: Then where do you see April-76, if not in excel? This is just a formatting-issue. Your data isn´t modified.

Comment: see my edit @Leon

Comment: And what is `ws`? I suppose it´s some kind of a stream. however it´s entirely unclear what type of stream. Please provide a bit more context on your problem.

Comment: First of all, you dont need string.Format if you dont use any placeholders. Then you maybe should set the corressponding column format of your worksheet, maybe like this: `ws["A"].NumberFormat = "@";` the @ symbol sets the column-format to text.

Comment: WS is stringWriter's object @HimBromBeere

Comment: That wasn´t my point. What is the type of the file being written? CSV? xml? xls? xslx? ...? And where do you see the whrong ouput? Also in excel? Did you look at the file with notepad as well? How does it look there?

Comment: in excel(.xls) file @HimBromBeere,in Libre Office it looks correct

Comment: then you see it´s just the formatting of excel which does not affect the actual data, but just how you see it in your client (in your case excel). So there´s absoluetely nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting to a txt or csv file there is no way to pass appropriate information to Excel. As @HimBromBeere pointed out, that is a matter of Excel's importing.

You could try to use a library like EPPlus (my favorite!) to create a real Excel file. In this file you can apply formatting to the cells, in this case use text format. Excel is then able to open the file rather than importing the data.